# MySQL TRIGGER to INSERT BEFORE INSERT using SELECT, IF, etc

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a trigger that combines an insert & select, I've found numerous topics online, but, none seem to relate to my exact problem, maybe I am missing something with my structure?

The aim of this is that on the event of a cancellation in our audit log, then I define a cancellation reason based on a series of business logic in another table, this logic is drawn together in a SELECT using CASE & subqueries.

I want to expand the following trigger that currently works and replace the SET cancellation_point='test' element with the SELECT query I just mentioned.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE

    TRIGGER `cancellation_stage` BEFORE INSERT ON `log` 
    FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN
IF (NEW.status='cancel' AND NEW.type='0') THEN
INSERT INTO cancellation_stage 
SET
id=NEW.id,
property_id=NEW.entity_id,
cancellation_date=NOW(),
cancellation_point='test';
END IF;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I did try to construct this myself using various guidance from here, but, its just not working. I got this code to physically save as a trigger, but, it did not populate the data in the database (I have replaced my SELECT with a basic query example below):

```
  DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `cancellation_stage` BEFORE INSERT ON `log` 
    FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN
DECLARE cancellation_point VARCHAR(255);
SET cancellation_point = ( SELECT * FROM x);
IF (NEW.transition='cancel' AND NEW.entity_type='property') THEN
INSERT INTO cancellation_stage 
SET
id=NEW.id,
property_id=NEW.entity_id,
cancellation_date=NOW(),
cancellation_point=NEW.cancellation_point;
END IF;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `SET cancellation_point = ( SELECT * FROM x)` generally isn't valid; it _might_ work if `x` only has one field. I also would stay away from naming the trigger the same thing as a table it inserts into; to at very least make things easier to read. (Edit: Ah, I am guessing that is a placeholder query for the more complex SELECT; it would probably be good to include that, or something closer to it.)

Comment: Thanks, they don't share the same name, I just removed some terms to make this seem more generic.  Yeah it is a placeholder query for a query that has 6 sub queries, I didn't want to go through the code and remove business references, I thought putting a placeholder would be suffice as my query works independently as a query.

Comment: Ah, I have just noticed (and perhaps it is a naming simplification creating the illusion of a potential issue) you've named your local variable the same as a field you are INSERTing to `cancellation_point`. I never used the INSERT... SET syntax that much, but potentially ambiguous identifiers have been known to cause difficult to diagnose issues in stored procedures.